# Using a function pointer with a trailing return type

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

There are some Stack Overflow users who strongly advocate always using the new C++11 trailing return type convention when writing functions, such as `main()->int`. I can see advantages, as it makes the notation uniform. However, when declaring a function pointer, I cannot find any way of using a trailing return form, i.e. can declare either

`typedef int(*fp)(int);`

or

`using fp = int(*)(int);`

for a function pointer taking an `int` and returning an `int`.

Is there a way of using the new trailing return syntax in declaring such a function pointer? For example, something like

`using fp = (*)(int)->int;`

but this doesn't compile. If not, is there a reason why the new syntax is not applicable to function pointers?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to use `auto`

```
using fp = auto (*)(int) -> int;
typedef auto (*fp)(int) -> int; // alternatively
```

Trailing return type syntax means you put the `auto` before the function name to indicate that the return type follows (or in the case of c++14, should be deduced).  For function pointers, the same rule applies except that it can't deduce it (for obvious reasons).

This is true for functions as well though, your example

```
main() -> int {... }
```

is not valid either without the preceding `auto`

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I forgot about the need of `auto` in trailing return type functions. Makes sense.

Comment: Just figured it out :) Thanks much, will accept your answer as was 5sec faster :)

Answer (score 15):

You want one of these depending on whether you are using `using` declaration or a `typedef`:

```
using fp = auto (*)(int)->int;
typedef auto (*gp)(int) -> int;
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I forgot about the need for `auto`.